# Access 2007 query date calculation

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

[image: Query Example]

I have the following Access query (see above) to give me the date, X number of weeks out from the actual WorkDte that exists in the table.  But, the date these expressions calculate out may not actually exists in the “CIB_Results” table due to a bank holiday etc.  Is there a way to generate the same sort of data but say if it’s running the “Wk1” calculation and it calculates out 1/1/2016 (which does not exists due to the new year holiday), instead of doing [WorkDte]-7 it will move on to [WorkDte]-14 and so on, until it finds an actual date that exists in the “CIB_Results” table?  I’m wanting to apply the same logic to all the fields in the query…that way they will all self adjust based off of the actual dates that exist in the “CIB_Results” table.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have a function `IsHoliday(SomeDate)` that looks up *SomeDate* in your holiday table and returns *True* if found.

Then create a loop:

```
Public Function PreviousWorkWeekday(ByVal SomeDate As Date) As Date

    Do
        SomeDate = DateAdd("ww", -1, SomeDate)
    Loop Until Not IsHoliday(SomeDate)
    PreviousWorkWeekday = SomeDate

End Function
```

Now use function `PreviousWorkWeekday` in your query.